# Match comma-separated values in SQL Server column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert multiple email into SQL Server table cell and before inserting them I need check whether the values are already there or not.

For more clarification

```
Row_id        EMAIL_ID
  1           abc@xyz.com,abcabc@xyz.com, abc2@xyz.com
  2           pqr@xyz.com,pqrabc@xyz.com
```

Now If I insert `abcabc@xyz.com,free@xyz.com`, it will show that value is duplicated.

I did this

```
select EMAIL_ID
from TR_DEMO
INNER JOIN dbo.split('abcabc@xyz.com,free@xyz.com', ',') s
ON s.items IN (select items from dbo.split(EMAIL_ID, ',') )
```

Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @String varchar(8000), 
    @Delimiter char(1)
)       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))       
as       
begin       
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(rtrim(ltrim(@slice)))       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return       
end
```

It works fine, but query is slow while checking the records around 100000

Can we do the same by wildcard or something else?

Comment: First normal form of database design says: you should never have more than one value inside a single cell. This makes all database operations really really painful and annoyingly complicated - don't do it. Rearchitect your solution - one value (at most!) per cell

Comment: the code is on production server, and this time i can't change my design, this cell is for inserting multiple emails.

Comment: Is Email_Value and Email_ID the same field and you've mislabelled by mistake?

Comment: @ChrisMoutray thanks for your comment, by mistake, Mislabelled

Comment: Feel like I'm going made where you trying to SELECT or INSERT emails that didn't exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a trick you can use for comparing against a comma-separated list.  First, you'll want to split your input list.  Then for each item, you'll want to check the following:

```
SELECT EMAIL_ID
  FROM TR_DEMO
 WHERE ','+EMAIL_ID+',' LIKE '%,abcabc@xyz.com,%'
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6dd71/2

Here's another example using your `SPLIT` method to generate the items:

```
    SELECT EMAIL_ID
      FROM TR_DEMO T
INNER JOIN dbo.split('abcabc@xyz.com,free@xyz.com', ',') s
               ON ','+T.EMAIL_ID+',' LIKE '%,'+s.items+',%'
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9a7b/1

Comment: @vikas: Were you able to test, and is it a lot faster?

Comment: yeah it is much faster and I modified my query : select
 EMAIL_ID
from TR_DEMO
INNER JOIN dbo.split('abcabc@xyz.com,free@xyz.com', ',') s
ON ','+replace(replace(replace(replace(EMAIL_ID,  CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), ''), ' ', '')+',' LIKE '%,' + items + ',%'

Comment: @vikas I appreciate that you're using a SELECT here and not INSERT as my answer has shown - but out of interest why wouldn't you do a general UPDATE against the tr_demo table using your replace rules first and then your JOIN wouldnt need to include the replace function - Its just that I wonder if the using a replace in the JOIN effects performance...

Comment: @ChrisMoutray Sorry for delay in comment, and thanks for your suggestion, replace in join effects performance, I will use the update query to remove the spaces

Answer (score 0):

Ok how about this

```
declare @EmailsToInsert varchar(max) = 'abcabc@xyz.com,free@xyz.com'

declare @insertdata table (email varchar(max))
insert into @insertdata select items from dbo.split(@EmailsToInsert, ',')

-- remove any trailing spaces
update tr_demo
set email_id = replace(email_id, ' ', '')

update t
set email_id = t.email_id + ',' + i.email
from tr_demo t
inner join @insertdata i on ',' + t.email_id + ',' not like '%,' + i.email + ',%'
```

- Split the string to insert into a temp table (I've used a table variable here).
- Remove any trailing spaces in the email_id field
- Update base on joining your data table and the temp table by assuming emails are wrapped with commas - note the commas added to start and end of email_id as part of the join

And here's a working example using table var's

```
declare @data table (row_id int, email_id varchar(max))
insert into @data values 
(1, 'abc@xyz.com,abcabc@xyz.com, abc2@xyz.com'),
(2, 'pqr@xyz.com,pqrabc@xyz.com')

declare @EmailsToInsert varchar(max) = 'abcabc@xyz.com,free@xyz.com'

declare @insertdata table (email varchar(max))
insert into @insertdata select items from dbo.split(@EmailsToInsert, ',')

update @data
set email_value = replace(email_value, ' ', '')

update t
set email_value = t.email_value + ',' + i.email
from @data t
inner join @insertdata i on ',' + t.email_value + ',' not like '%,' + i.email + ',%' 

select * from @data
```