# SQL Server WHERE with wildcard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to use a wildcard for the `where in` statement in SQL Server 2008?

For example, I currently have:

```
SELECT something  
FROM myTable  
WHERE    (ORG + '-' + ORGSUB like '5015001-________' or
          ORG + '-' + ORGSUB like '5015018-________' or 
          ORG + '-' + ORGSUB like '_______-________')
```

I need to do it this way:

```
SELECT something  
FROM myTable 
WHERE
   (ORG + '-' + ORGSUB) in( '5015001-________','5015018-________','_______-________')
```

i'm going to be passing those values through a stored procedure as a comma delimited list. is there another way to get it done?

Comment: I don't see why not. Have you tried it?

Comment: nope. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx  `in` does not support wildcards the way `like` does.

Comment: You can't do it the second way. Your top query should work.

Comment: i'm going to be passing those values through a stored procedure as a comma delimited list. is there another way to get it done?

Comment: What values are you going to be passing?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350106/how-to-use-like-clause-with-in-caluse-in-sql-server

Comment: i will be passing in something like: "5015001-________,5015018-________,_______-________"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your comma delimited list, split it, and insert it into a temp table...

You can then use a `LIKE` statement in a `JOIN` to this temp table:

```
SELECT something
FROM myTable mt
JOIN #tempTable tt
    ON mt.ORG + '-' + mt.ORGSUB LIKE tt.SearchValue
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you even care about `ORGSUB` in your query (as provided in the example)?
Seems to me you should rewrite your `WHERE` clause to look for the components separately, e.g.:

```
SELECT something  
FROM myTable  
WHERE ORG IN (5015001, 5015018, ...) 
[add other criteria as appropriate]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why a comma-separated list?

```
DECLARE TYPE dbo.OrgSub AS TABLE(s VARCHAR(32));
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SearchOrgSubs
  @OrgSub dbo.OrgSub READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT t.something 
    FROM dbo.mytable AS t
    INNER JOIN @OrgSub AS o
    ON t.ORG + '-' + t.ORGSUB = o.s;
END
GO
```

Now you can pass the *set* into the stored procedure from C# or wherever, without first having to form it into a comma-separated list.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temp Table contains the result of a `split` function.

```
SELECT somthing 
from myTable  
    JOIN dbo.Split('5015001-________','5015018-________','_______-________') as Splits 
    on (ORG + '-' + ORGSUB) like Splits.items
```

Comment: what is Splits.items in your query?. i'm getting Invalid column name 'items'.

Comment: @TanyaXrum : Because you have to create your split function which simply takes your comma-separated string and return a table contains them. - Useful demo that I've found http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9a7b/1 - Similar Question http://stackoverflow.com/a/12091987/461564